# Predictive text no longer works as well, e.g. neither "aren" nor "aren't" suggests "aren't"

Tags: ios, keyboard

My method of typing quickly on iOS has really gotten slow lately due to predictive text suggestions changing.

Many simple contraction words no longer pop up in the predictive text, causing me to either not type the apostrophe which I dont like (see what I mean?) or slow my down by going into the menu I'd rather access through a quick tap on the text predictions.

Here's some examples. Actually "Id" => "I'd" is still working.

Is there a way to fix this? I tried turning predictive text off then back on, and it didn't fix the issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Settings > General > Keyboard > Text Replacement

Tap the + icon, the first field is for the desired result, and the second you can leave blank (to allow text replacement to put the result in the predictive text bar) or you can put a common misspelling in the bottom field.

So:

```
Phrase: I’m 
Shortcut: Im
```

You can create automatic replacements for common typing errors, or entire paragraphs of text if you desire.

Eg:

```
Phrase: [paragraph of text]
Shortcut: [short text code you can easily remember]
```